# Does it make sense to build a music making app on top of a game engine?

Tags: android, ios, graphics, opengl-es, unity-game-engine

I'm interested in making an app which would allow sequencing audio instruments and drums in real time, which would work on several mobile platforms. The visual interface I designed is quite elaborate, and I'm definitely going to need custom graphics capabilities.

The way I see it, I have two options. **1.** Learn OpenGL ES and build something relatively cross-platform, and then wrap it with layers that can interact with specific OS API's. **2.** Use a 2d game engine, e.g [Unity 2D](http://unity3d.com/pages/2d-power?gclid=CNTi9qKBorwCFUSSfgod9H0ADg), and utilize that to build a responsive interface.

Option 1 is the most difficult, since I've never programmed graphics before, while option 2 may be an overkill since audio processing apps require lots of processing power lots of low-level optimization for DSP routines. Losing some of this power to an entire game engine may be undesirable.

It's very important that I don't have to reimplement the interface from scratch for every platform. It's buggy and error prone, and a pain to manage.

I'd like some feedback on the best way to go about evaluating my options. Has someone looked into something like this already?

Comment: Why aren't [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk), or [Qt](https://qt-project.org/) , suitable?

Comment: Because it needs to run on more than just Android. I want to build a universal backend that I could later wrap with Android, iOS or other OS layers.

Comment: Ok, did you look at Qt, or other cross platform application / UI platform?

Comment: Yes, of course you could use a game engine. I would also look at Qt Quick 2 -- it runs on Android now and offer game-like performance of animated UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been done already, i believe i saw it on the unity forums,
as for whether or not it makes sense, sure it does,
Unity does something that is truly amazing, you can develop it once and deploy to iPhone, Android and WP and more, instead of using xCode with sound effect plugins unity comes with fmod that is easy to tap into.
Not something i am going to do, but if i did, unity would be perfect for it especially when you think that you can have play functions with amazing visual ques that unity is made for.
Lol, sounds like a sales pitch, but no, its not a bad idea to choose unity for such a thing. since you can always write the missing features in plugins if needed. beats going to OpenGL which is a pain in the {bug}